# Default methods in Java interfaces: How to JavaDoc?

Tags: java, java-8, javadoc

I checked several default methods in JDK 8 interface (like Function#compose(Function)) to learn how to document the default implementation of a interface method.

As far as I can see the JavaDoc does not refer to the default implementation but only to the general description of the interface method.

What is the expectation of users of an API? Where would they look for that kind of documentation?

Comment: I would look for the Javadoc on the interface which defined it whether it had a default implementation or not. i.e. I don't think making a method `default` changes how it is Javadoc'ed

Comment: Function.compose() is not intended to be overridden. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator- for a default method which (of course) provides a default implementation, but is intended to be overridden by some subclasses. It describes the contract of the method, and the default implementation details.

Comment: @JBNizet how is it documented that it is not intended to be overridden? :)

Comment: @AndyTurner `@FunctionalInterface` gives a big hint.

Comment: The “general description of the interface method” is fine. There is no requirement to document the implementation details and API users should not expect to find some. Yes, there are *some* cases where implementation details are mentioned, but that doesn’t say that you should consider this a general pattern. Details of the `default` implementation may be useful to provide a hint about why implementations should override it.